# Clarification needed on ordering $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ in the language of arithmetic.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I have been reading the book by richard kaye, on peano arithmetic.
In section 2.1, he gave the following statement.

"$\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is made into a $L_A$ structure by defining an order $<$ making $X$ 'infinitely large' "

($L_A$ here means language of arithmetic)

So exactly what does the author meant by that statement, I pondered about it for a way and cant figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It turns out that the orderings are completely determined by how $X$ compares to rational numbers. The author is  referring to the ordering where $X$ is greater than every rational number. The other available places are: **(1)** $X$ is less than every rational number, **(2)** $X$ acts like some particular irrational number, **(3)** $X$ is infinitesimally greater than a rational number $r$ (i.e. $r<X<s$ for every $s>r$), and **(4)** $X$ is infinitesimally less than a rational number $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out, it's not entirely clear what the author meant but I have a good feeling that I know what they had in mind:

$L_{A}$ - the language of arithmetic - includes two constant symbols $\dot{0},\dot{1}$, one (or two - depending on your convention) relation symbols $\dot{\prec}$ (,\dot{=}) and two function symbols $\dot{\circ}$ and $\dot{+}$. If we want to consider $\mathbb Z[X]$ as an $L_{A}$-structure, we must decide how to interpret all these symbols in this structure. The interpretation of $\dot{0}, \dot{1}$ should be clear (it's the zero polynomial and constant polynomial with value $1 \in \mathbb Z$ respectively). The interpretation of $\dot{\circ}, \dot{+}$ is given by polynomial multiplication and addition respectively. The interpretation of $\dot{=}$ is equality.

What remains now is the interpretation of $\dot{\prec}$. Call this interpretation $<$. We want that $(\mathbb Z[X]; 0,1, +, \circ, \prec)$ is an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) and here is what we can do to achieve this.

1. Let $f, g \in \mathbb Z[X]$ be constant polynomials. We let $$f \prec g : \iff f(0) \lt g(0), $$ where $\lt$ is the natural strict order of $\mathbb Z$.
2. For any constant polynomial $f \in \mathbb Z[X]$, we let $f \prec X$,
3. We now expand $\prec$ to all polynomials via the rules for ordered rings, i.e. if $f \prec g$ and $0 \prec h$ then $f \circ h \prec g \circ h$ and the second rule: If $f \prec g$ then for all $h \in \mathbb Z[X] \colon f + h \prec g + h$.

Evaluating $\prec$ with only this information given can be quite painful so let me spare you some time and tell you that
$$
f \prec g \iff g-f \text{ has non-negative leading coefficient}.
$$
It's a good exercise to prove that this equivalence holds.

Comment: So 'infinitely large' comes in when we compare the degree 1 monic $X$ with any constant polynomial ?

Comment: Yes, infinitely large here means larger than all constant polynomials.

Comment: $\circ$ is not a great symbol for multiplication, since it looks like composition (and people do study polynomials with composition as an operation).

Comment: @Hurkyl I agree but $*$ isn't any better - as it is usually used for folding and I thought $\cdot$ was a poor choice in this case because $\dot{\cdot}$ looks strange. So I ran out of ideas and settled on $\circ$ as the least bad choice.

Comment: @StefanMesken Why not $\times$?

Comment: By "folding", are you referring to the higher order operation in functional programming? My guess is that a large majority of people reading this page associate $*$ more strongly with multiplication, and indeed have never even heard of folding.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry, I didn't know that in English we don't use the literal translation of that operation's German name. What I was referring to is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of polynomials.

Comment: Ohh, that makes more sense, given the domain $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach (but it yields the same ordering as in Stefan Mesken's answer):

Let $A$ be a nonstandard model of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ and let $a \in A$ be a nonstandard number $>0$. Then, the map
$$\mathbb{Z}[X] \to A,\phantom{aaa}f(X) \mapsto f(a)$$ 
is an injective ring homomorphism. (Injectivity follows from the fact that the map has trivial kernel. This can be proved by using the overspill principle which is stated in Kaye's book.) Therefore, we can view $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as a subring of $A$ and a subring of an ordered ring is also ordered (simply restrict $<$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$).